Japanese film about epidemic with child carriers
I'm trying to remember the name of a Japanese film I watched, was wondering if anyone knows? A friend showed me this film while we were still in high school, so about 2001-2005.
The film was about Japan being struck with some kind of epidemic, and kids were the carriers. They can infect adults by physical contact, which quickly becomes fatal. An isolation zone somewhere in the country is created and all the kids are ferried there by truck and left there to prevent the epidemic from spreading.
Unfortunately, that's about all I can remember, I only watched for a brief moment. Any ideas is much appreciated.

Are you trying to say that you saw the film around the year 2003-4 or 2013-4? Do you recall if the film was new or at least looked like it was new at that time? Was the film live action or animated?

it's live action, and was between 2000 to 2005. Can't tell if the film was a new feature at the time or not.

Are you certain it was a Japanese movie?  
The one that seems closest to your description is 感染列島 (Kansen Rettō, "Infectious Islands", referred to as "Pandemic"):
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1185654/ 
However, it is more recent (2009) than what you were mentioning.

This ought to be a comment

Pretty sure this isn't it, the focus of the film is mainly the kids. The epidemic might not be your typical virus. I remember it only seems to target and kills adults, but kids are largely immune to it.
